# How to set rtl property based on language change in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i am developing angularjs application and it is multilingual application with english and arabic. Whenever i select arabic language i want to apply rtl support to html tag.  will work fine but i want to do this based on the language selection.

Below is my html code

```
<div class="language">
 <a href="#" ng-click="changeLanguage(lang == 'de_AR' ? 'de_EN' : 'de_AR')">
  <img ng-src="images/{{ lang == 'de_AR' ? 'english.png' : 'arabic.png' }}" />
 </a>
</div>
```

Below is my angular code

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function (lang) {
  $scope.lang = lang == 'de_AR' ? 'de_AR' : 'de_EN';
  $cookieStore.put("PreferredLanguage", $scope.lang);
  $translate.use($scope.lang);
}
```

In the above code if the language selected then i want to add  otherwise simply . I tried as below.

```
if($scope.lang="de_AR")
{
 $scope.rtl="rtl"
}
```

Below is my html tag.

```
<html ng-app="RoslpApp"  dir="{{rtl}}">
```

Above code doesnt provide rtl support. May i get some help to fix this? May i know am i missing something here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Vivz. i changed but it is not working. i inspected and i can see dir="" class="ng-scope" in html element.

Comment: Try using ng-class="{'directions':lang=='de_AR'}"  .directions{ direction: rtl; }

Comment: i added as <html ng-app="RoslpApp" ng-class="{'direction':rtl}">. What should i write in controller?

Comment: Try like above, i.e if lang=='de_AR', then apply class directions and put directions in your css

Comment: i added html { 
    direction:ltr;
} in css.  Now how can i add class?  if ($scope.lang == "de_AR")
        {
         //how to add class? 
        }

Comment: remove dir and just simply put ng-class="{'directions':lang=='de_AR'}" in your html tag and add class to ur css .directions{ direction: rtl; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do ternary operations on `$scope.lang` to decide whether the page should be ltr or rtl

```
<html ng-app="RoslpApp" ng-controller="RoslpAppController"  dir="{{lang=='de_AR'?'rtl':'ltr'}}">
```

You have to define your ternary conditions within the scope of your controller to trigger. So place your `ng-controller` on html tag or move your dir to the place where you are defining `ng-controller`